# what is tomcat default GC option?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

in `catalina.sh` I set `JAVA_OPTS` like this.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
```

in this case what is default `GC` option?

I think default option is serial GC.`(-XX:+UseSerialGC)`

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) says:

> On server-class machines running the server VM, the garbage collector
>   (GC) has changed from the previous serial collector (-XX:+UseSerialGC)
>   to a parallel collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC). You can override this
>   default by using the -XX:+UseSerialGC command-line option to the java
>   command.

As you are forcing the server VM using `-server`, this also applies to you.

You can always double check this with JConsole through JMX.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Tomcat sets something different it's the same as the default for the JVM.